# how to use everest-js to createNote?

Tags: node.js, evernote

I'm using https://github.com/berryboy/everest-js

and want to post some note to my evernote,

but this project don't show example to create, anyone could show an example?

or Is there any REST API for evernote?

Answer (score 1):

We do not have a JavaScript SDK yet, but there are others that might be helpful (Ruby,PHP). You can find them [here](https://github.com/organizations/evernote).

Comment: Is there any plan for js sdk? or offer an REST+OAUTH API?

Comment: It has been published : http://blog.evernote.com/tech/2013/03/07/new-javascript-sdk-for-evernote-developers/